# UWP Problems Setting GridView Items source using x:Bind

Tags: c#, gridview, mvvm, data-binding, win-universal-app

I am trying to populate my gridview with Photos from the Pictures library using data virtualization and compiled binding.

I've taken the Microsoft UWP ([Data Virtualization Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDataVirtualization)) and using its FileSource as my base, I modified it to use my own Picture object and tried to apply it to my UWP app. All I am getting is a blank page, and the designer is throwing an exception.

I want to use x:Bind to bind to my data source object in my model as I am using MVVM and don't want code-behind.

I couldn't get this to work in my app so I wrote a small test app that isn't even MVVM and tried to use x:Bind with my data source as an object in the code behind and it fails as to bind to the collection as well.

I can get this work with my Picture object if I set the gridview's source directly in my code-behind (which is what the sample is doing).

```
 async void initdata()
 {
    StorageLibrary pictures = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
    string path = pictures.SaveFolder.Path;

    FileDataSource ds = await FileDataSource.GetDataSoure(path);
    if (ds.Count > 0)
    {
        PicturesGrid.ItemsSource = ds;
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage.Current.NotifyUser("Error: The pictures folder doesn't contain any files", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

The FileDataSource is defined as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// A custom datasource over the file system that supports data virtualization
/// </summary>
public class FileDataSource : INotifyCollectionChanged, System.Collections.IList, IItemsRangeInfo
{
   ...
}
```

In my code, I have created the PicturesCollection as a property:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public FileDataSource _PicturesCollection;
    public FileDataSource PicturesCollection { get; private set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        PicturesGrid.ContainerContentChanging += PicturesGrid_ContainerContentChanging;
        PicturesCollection = null;
        initdata();
    }

    private void PicturesGrid_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!args.InRecycleQueue)
        {
            // Sets a textblock in each item indicating its index
            //FrameworkElement ctr = (FrameworkElement)args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot;
            //if (ctr != null)
            //{
            //    TextBlock t = (TextBlock)ctr.FindName("idx");
            //    t.Text = args.ItemIndex.ToString();
            //}
        }
    }

    async void initdata()
    {
        StorageLibrary pictures = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
        string path = pictures.SaveFolder.Path;

        _PicturesCollection = await FileDataSource.GetDataSoure(path);

        if (_PicturesCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            PicturesCollection = _PicturesCollection;
            //PicturesGrid.ItemsSource = ds;
        }

    }
}
```

and bound it to my GridView:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <GridView x:Name="PicturesGrid"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind PicturesCollection}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Picture" >
                <Grid Width="200" Height="80">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="DimGray" Opacity="0.8" />

                    <Image Width ="130"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           Source="{x:Bind ImageThumbNail, Converter ={StaticResource StorageItemThumbnailoImageSourceConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                               MaxHeight="30"
                               Text="{x:Bind Name}"
                               Foreground="White"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

This gives me a blank page, but if I set it in code-behind, it works. Can anyone tell me why this is so? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when your page loaded, your `PicturesCollection` property is not set, so your `PicturesGrid`'s `ItemsSource` is `null` and you can sell noting is you page.

In the constructor of your `MainPage`, you are using `initdata` method to get all data. However this method is `async void` and you didn't wait for its finishing. Actually, we also can't use `await` in constructor. So when your page loaded, the execution of `await FileDataSource.GetDataSoure(path);` may be not finished, you `PicturesCollection` property is still `null` here, but your `PicturesGrid`'s `ItemsSource` has bound to your `PicturesCollection` property. Thus, the `ItemsSource` is null and you can see nothing. Although your `PicturesCollection` property will be set to the real data later, but you didn't implement property-change notification for your `PicturesCollection` property. And for `x:Bind` the default `Mode` is `OneTime`, so your `PicturesGrid`'s `ItemsSource` will always be `null`.

To fix this issue, you can implement property-change notification for `PicturesCollection` property like following:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private FileDataSource _PicturesCollection;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public FileDataSource PicturesCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _PicturesCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_PicturesCollection != value)
            {
                _PicturesCollection = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    ...

    private async void initdata()
    {
        StorageLibrary pictures = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
        string path = pictures.SaveFolder.Path;

        var source = await FileDataSource.GetDataSoure(path);

        if (source.Count > 0)
        {
            PicturesCollection = source;
        }
    }
}
```

And in XAML, set the `Mode` of `x:Bind` to `OneWay` like:

```
<GridView x:Name="PicturesGrid"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind PicturesCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
    ...
</GridView>
```

After this, your `x:Bind` will work.

**Updata:**

If you only need one-time bindings for asynchronously-loaded data, you can force one-time bindings to be initialized by calling **`this.Bindings.Update();`** after you've loaded data like following:

```
async void initdata()
{
    StorageLibrary pictures = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
    string path = pictures.SaveFolder.Path;

    _PicturesCollection = await FileDataSource.GetDataSoure(path);

    if (_PicturesCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        PicturesCollection = _PicturesCollection;

        this.Bindings.Update();
    }
}
```

It’s much cheaper to initialize them this way than it is to have one-way bindings and to listen for changes as it only need to add one method in your code. However, this may be not a good practice when using MVVM. For more info, please see **If your data loads asynchronously** in [Binding object declared using {x:Bind}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#binding-object-declared-using-x-bind-)

> Code to support **{x:Bind}** is generated at compile-time in the partial classes for your pages. These files can be found in your **`obj`** folder, with names like (for C#) **`<view name>.g.cs`**. The generated code includes a handler for your page's [**Loading**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208706) event, and that handler calls the **Initialize** method on a generated class that represent's your page's bindings. **Initialize** in turn calls **Update** to begin moving data between the binding source and the target. **Loading** is raised just before the first measure pass of the page or user control. So if your data is loaded asynchronously it may not be ready by the time **Initialize** is called. So, after you've loaded data, you can force one-time bindings to be initialized by calling **`this->Bindings->Update();`**. If you only need one-time bindings for asynchronously-loaded data then it’s much cheaper to initialize them this way than it is to have one-way bindings and to listen for changes. If your data does not undergo fine-grained changes, and if it's likely to be updated as part of a specific action, then you can make your bindings one-time, and force a manual update at any time with a call to **Update**.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. This is what I suspected was happening but I had no idea how to go about resolving it. I am just starting out with XAML and MVVM so sometimes I miss the simple things. The more I do the more I learn though.

Answer (score 0):

To use x:Bind in UWP you should define an object of the ViewModel in XAML like this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Name="MyViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

And refer to it like this:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.PicturesCollection}"
```

x:Bind can only bind from a ViewModel object that is predefined in XAML.

Comment: Thanks, I already have the view model set in my XAML, I just didn't show that in my code sample. I'll add the view model name to my x:Bind.

Comment: You've confused `Binding` with `x:Bind`. For `Binding`, we need to set `DataContext`. But `x:Bind` does not use the DataContext as a default source—instead, it uses the page or user control itself. So it will look in the code-behind of your page or user control for properties, fields, and methods. To expose your view model to {x:Bind}, you will typically want to add new fields or properties to the code behind for your page or user control.

Comment: For more info, see [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) and [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt210946).

Comment: That's not true... `{x:Bind}` binds to all properties that can be accessed from `this`, or globally (with namespace), doesn't have to declare them in the XAML.
`{x:Bind SomeProperty}` resolves to `this.SomeProperty`.