# Random access data virtualization with FlipView

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, flipview

Does the FlipView control (I'm programming Universal Windows) support binding to a random access (virtualized) data source?

The Microsoft docs [ListView and GridView data virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization) suggest that it works for grid and list view but say nothing about FlipView.

I have a grid working against a FileDataSource collection taken from the Universal Windows samples collection but the Flipview just displays blank pages when I try to bind it to it's own copy of the same data source -- see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350348/problems-setting-flipview-items-source-using-data-virtualization) about the same thing.

Comment: Random access Virtualization only support GridView and ListView. But FlipView already support Virtualization, it takes VirtualizingStackPanel as its default ItemsPanel.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm new to XAML and UWP and it's control set so yes, I may very well be using a control for something it's not intended to be used for. Trying to keep my data structures and memory footprint small led me to the random access virtualization. I didn't want to abandon the flipview if it was just something simple I didn't know to add/set or call. Working on a different approach now.